# django template with tags not rendering to variable

Tags: django, shell, templates

I have a property on a model that is rendering a template and setting it as a part of the context available to the next template, here is the method:

models.py:

```
@property
def detail_body_rendered(self):
    ctx = self.context()

    link_ctx = template.Context({'the_message': self.message})
    render_url = template.Template("{% load url from future %}<a href=\"{% url 'message_redirect' 'message' the_message.pk %}\">Click Here</a>").render(link_ctx)
    ctx['link'] = render_url

    return template.Template(self.message.detail_body).render(ctx)
```

This works great if the returned value is being sent through the template system:

inbox.html:

```
...
<div class="detail_message_body">{{ current_message.detail_body_rendered }}</div>
...
```

Everything happens as expected, the `detail_body_rendered` property replaces tags stored in the database with the context and the link displays on the page. Yay.

It also works in the shell. However, if I have a message object anywhere else, and request that property, it fails silently on the line with the template in it. Specifically, because of the % signs in there. If I take those out, no problemo.

So my question is twofold, why is it blowing up when I request it everywhere except in a template file or in the shell, and how do I make the error message verbose so that I can actually see why it's choking in the terminal window?

Comment: I imagine that by having the `message` somewhere else, afterward it's no longer in the context (as messages are only shown once), so when you try to render the template in your property, `the_message` is then `None` and raising a template exception (that is failing silently). You can try turn `TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True` in your settings to raise template errors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Timmy, but I can print the message out in the line before the one that fails, and it is still a valid object. I might have confused things a bit by calling my object `message`, it is not a django message, but an instance of one of my classes.